# In kotlin,parameter variables are created as local 'val' variables that can’t be reused for other values

Tags: kotlin

hi i am newbie in kotlin and have a confusion about parameter variables they are created as local 'val' variables that can’t be reused for other values. 
for example:

```
fun myFunction(mesg:String){
 mesg="hi" //local val variables that can’t be reused for other values
}
```

but the below code is working fine

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val abc = arrayOf("A", "B", "C")
    updateArray(abc)

    println(abc[2])// print Z
}

fun updateArray(abcParam: Array<String>) {
    abcParam[2] = "Z" // 
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't change whole parameter. You just add a new item to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that in kotlin everything is passed to functions by values. For primitive types it is okay and pretty obvious that you can not change variable passed by value. But if we talk about objects, its **reference** is getting passed to function, so you can not change only reference passed to function, but free to change object that reference points to.
Thats why you are able to change elements of array but can not change string.